# Missed UK entry clearance valid until date. What now?

Tags: uk-visa

It's a bit of a strange (stupid) case: I was granted an entry clearance for a UK Tier 1 visa (applied from South Africa). For numerous reasons (some medical), I couldn't travel before the "Valid until" date. But I didn't pay sufficient attention to the date or make any attempts to change it.

Given that I've already been granted a visa that was supposed to last a year, will I have to start the entire process again? Or could I just apply for entry? As I'm writing this, that second option seems highly unlikely but figured I'd ask. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Tier 1 General visas are now closed but other tier 1 types are still open ( https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-general ). Also, do you still qualify or have your personal circumstances changed?

Comment: I was granted a Tier 1 GE. Circumstances haven't changed in any meaningful way, why do you ask?

Comment: @user16259 likely asked as, from 6 April 2018, applications for Tier 1 General ceased to be accepted. The impending closure of that route was announced in 2015.

Comment: Looks like Graduate Entrepreneur tier 1 visas are still open. Unless someone adds a better answer, I suggest asking the organisation (DIT or University) that endorsed your application what they recommend.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's useful for the future:
I had to apply for a "Vignette transfer", which essentially allows you to get a new entry clearance document. I submitted the application with documents from my previous application. Will post the outcome.

Thanks to everyone who chipped in.